# How to prove $\mathbb{R}$x$\mathbb{N}$ is not enumerable

Tags: first-order-logic

How to prove $\mathbb{R}$x$\mathbb{N}$ is not enumerable?
I dont know how to prove these, i know $\mathbb{R}$ is not enumarable so $\mathbb{R}$x$\mathbb{N}$ can be enumareble. Please i need help.

Comment: What do you know about comparing cardinalities? How would one show that one cardinality is at least as big as another, for instance?

Comment: Well, you have an injective function $\mathbb{R} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{N}$ and you know that the reals are **not** countable. What if you could countably list all of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{N}$, couldn't you backtrack and countably list all the reals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know $\Bbb R$ is not enumerable, you can inject it into $\Bbb {R \times N}$ by $x \to (x,1)$ to show $\Bbb {R \times N}$ is not enumerable.

Comment: Thanks, i forgot about injections to compare cardinality.